# Joining three tables in R each having different keys

Tags: r, join

I have three tables: CUSTOMER (PK: CustomerNum), RESERVATION (PK: CustomerNum and TripID NOT PK), and TRIP (PK: TripID). Trying to use purr:reduce.

Tried the following code.

```
tables <- list(customer, reservation, trip)
reduce(tables, inner_join, by = c("CustomerNum", "TripID"))
```

Error: `by` can't contain join column `TripID` which is missing from LHS

Comment: The by columns are not common in all the datasets  (`CUSTOMER` doesn't have that column`

Comment: I know that from the error. So there is no way to use purrr if the three tables have two different columns. Correct?

Comment: Either create that column or don't provide the `by`, then it will figure out the common column by name

Comment: This is the correct query returning 27 rows: 
customer %>%
  inner_join(reservation, by = "CustomerNum") %>%
  inner_join(trip, by = "TripID") %>%
  select(CustomerNum, LastName, FirstName, TripName)

Comment: But when I use 
tables <- list(customer, reservation, trip)
reduce(tables, inner_join) it returns only 2 rows. So

Comment: Are you saying that for the first two datasets, you want to join by a different column, and then the joined dataset with the third with other column?

Comment: Correct. Join the first two by CustomerNum and the third one by TripNum

Comment: Then, I think a  `for` loop might be better or use indexing

Answer (score 1):

We can use a `for` loop when the `by` columns are different in each step

```
grp <- c("CustomerNum", "TripID")
out <- customer
for(i in seq_along(grp)) {
     out <- inner_join(out, tables[[i+1]], by = grp[i])
  }

out
#  CustomerNum        val TripID newInfo
#1           1 -0.5458808      4       *
#2           2  0.5365853      2    ****
```

then `select` the columns of interest

---

Note that if we don't provide the `by`, it would automatically pick up the `by` based on the availability of common column name based on the reproducible example below.  As the OP didn't provide any reproducible example, it is unclear about the situation

```
reduce(tables, inner_join)
#Joining, by = "CustomerNum"  #### <-----
#Joining, by = "TripID"       #### <-----
#  CustomerNum        val TripID newInfo
#1           1 -0.5458808      4       *
#2           2  0.5365853      2    ****
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
customer <- data.frame(CustomerNum = 1:5, val = rnorm(5))
reservation <- data.frame(CustomerNum = 1:3, TripID = c(4, 2, 8))
trip <- data.frame(TripID = c(4, 9, 2), newInfo = c("*", "**", "****"))
tables <- list(customer, reservation, trip)
```